# Is the giant who carved the "Under Me" line Time?

Tags: c-s-lewis, the-chronicles-of-narnia

In *The Silver Chair*, Rilian, while enchanted, said:

> > Though under Earth and throneless now I be,
> >     Yet, while I lived, all Earth was under me.
>
> From which it is plain that some great king of the ancient giants, who lives<sup>1</sup> buried there, caused this boast to be cut in the stone over his sepulcher;...
>   <sub>-*The Chronicles of Narnia: The Silver Chair*, chapter 10</sub>

And before, when they are traveling to the Underworld:

> "That is old Father Time, who was once a king in Overland," said the Warden.  "And now he has sunk down into the Deep Realm and lies dreaming of all the things that are done in the upper world. Many sink down, and few return to the sunlit lands. They say he will wake at the end of the world."
>   <sub>-*The Chronicles of Narnia: The Silver Chair*, chapter 10</sub>

Now, Time fits the description of the scene that Rilian gave: He's a giant, he was a king, and he is located under the carving.

**Was Father Time the one to have the message carved in the stone?**

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> Yes, it says "lives buried" in my version.</sub>

Comment: Are there versions where it doesn't say "lives buried"? Grammatically, it's fine as long as the 'who' refers to the "great king" and not the "ancient giants." Based on the rest of the sentence, the latter wouldn't make sense ("caused it to be cut in the stone over **his** sepulcher").

Comment: Oh! Now I see the problem. Is that bad writing or a typo in the original text?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## It appears so.

Since nobody else answered with an explanation of how everything fits, I decided to go ahead and post my own.

- **Though under Earth and throneless now I be**

This certainly applies - he is buried and has no crown.

> "And now he has sunk down into the Deep Realm and lies dreaming of all the things that are done in the upper world. Many sink down, and few return to the sunlit lands. They say he will wake at the end of the world."
> <sub>-*The Chronicles of Narnia: The Silver Chair*, chapter 10</sub>

- **Yet, while I lived, all Earth was under me.**

If he was a king, then metaphorically, yes, he's above everyone else.

- **From which it is plain that some great king of the ancient giants, who lives buried there, caused this boast to be cut in the stone over his sepulcher;**

> "That is old Father Time, who was once a king in Overland," said the Warden.
> <sub>-*The Chronicles of Narnia: The Silver Chair*, chapter 10</sub>

So he was king, and we see that he is a giant:

> And here, filling almost the whole length of it, lay an enormous man fast asleep. He was far bigger than any of the giants, and his face was not like a giant's, but noble and beautiful.
> <sub>-*The Chronicles of Narnia: The Silver Chair*, chapter 10</sub>

Also - **who else would it be?**

Is there any other giant king that we know of buried right there?

It seems entirely possible that it was time who had it carved.

Comment: Just to be pedantic: the last quote does not show that Father Time is a giant, but rather that he is *not* a giant: "He was *far bigger* than any of the giants, and his face was *not like a giant's*, but noble and beautiful." (Of course, he would be a giant in the less precise sense of "humanoid larger than humans.") Rilian probably doesn't know of any large humanoids other than the giants, so he assumes that the king of this large-scale city with a large-scale inscription must have been a giant.

Answer (score -2):

I think he is the most likely option. From reviewing the books and skimming, he seems to most definitely be the only giant located under the carving. However, he isn't the only king, but in my view, "who lives buried there" is the more important criterion and as the giant Time fulfills both, I think he is the most likely option.

Comment: "*From reviewing the literature*" - this is a bit vague. Sorry, but I'm downvoting because this answer is unsupported and your reasoning is unclear.

Comment: This would be better if you included a line by line explanation of how it fits.

Comment: @Mithrandir I, unfortunately, don't have time to do that, but if someone else were to do so, I would remove my answer and upvote theirs.

Comment: @Benjamin You might want to follow through on removing this answer then